# Why did Mayday Parker want to fight crime like her father did?

Tags: marvel, comics, character-motivation, spider-man

Mayday wanted to fight crime like her dad, Peter Parker/Spider-Man, did before he retired in the [MC2 continuity](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Comics_2). He told her not to, but she decided to do it anyway. Why?

Comment: Because if she didn't it wouldn't make for a very long series...

Answer (score 9):

Although Peter never intended for his daughter, May, to become a superhero -- or to learn that he was Spider-Man, before he retired due to an injury -- it's repeatedly stated that her parents raised her to have a strong sense of responsibility.

> MAYDAY: **Your parents raised you to have a real sense of responsibility.** And yet, in a misguided effort to protect you, they're now trying to convince you to turn your back on your powers -- and the potential good you might accomplish!
>
> [image: Spider-Girl Vol. 1 #4, page 5]
>
> <sub>*[Spider-Girl Vol. 1 #4](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Girl_Vol_1_4)* (January, 1999)</sub>

She was also aware that Peter's late uncle, [Ben Parker](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Benjamin_Parker_(Earth-982)), was killed because Peter allowed a criminal to go free, and after her spider-powers emerged, May repeatedly found herself in situations where friends or family members would likely have gotten hurt or been killed if she hadn't intervened. One such example is when a supervillain attacked her high school in *Spider-Girl Vol. 1 #4*.

This sense of responsibility is likely the main reason she continued to fight crime, against her father's wishes, although she admitted that being a superhero was a rush at times as well.

> MAYDAY: **I'll admit that this hero deal can be a real rush at times,** but try to think of all the good I can do!
>
> [image: Spider-Girl Vol. 1 #5, page 3]
>
> <sub>*[Spider-Girl Vol. 1 #5](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Girl_Vol_1_5)* (February, 1999)</sub>